# Write new entry into cell and autofit column width if it needs to become wider to fit the new entry?

Tags: vba, excel

I write a value into a cell:

```
Range("A1").Value = 13/3/2015
```

If the column is wide enough to accommodate that entry, I don't want it to change. If it is not wide enough, I want it to autofit. What is the best way of doing this?

The following should work

```
Range("A1").Value = 13/3/2015
Width = Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Autofit
if Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth < Width then Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Width
```

But I hope that there is a more clever way that does not require me to autofit the column width needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Autofit will adjust to the longest cell width in the column, provided wordwrap is no on. It will not change it if a larger width is not found. Your extra test is redundant.